# Rails: checkbox list across classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If in a form I have resources loaded like so:

```
def custom_articles
  @user.custom_articles + @user.edited_articles || []
end
```

And they're outputted into a checkbox list, how can I differentiate between what is an `EditedArticle` and what is a `CustomArticle`? `custom_articles` are added to a collection of `Component`s too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to keep the context, then keep the context!  Instead of passing back an array, why can't you pass back a hash that won't step on the type?

```
def custom_articles
  {custom: @user.custom_articles, edited: @user.edited_articles}
end
```

edited:

```
  custom_articles[:edited]
```

custom:

```
  custom_articles[:custom]
```

all articles:

```
  custom_articles.values.flatten
```